# Android GPS not working in service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Im trying to get my GPS working in a service but its not working. The GPS bit works on its own but not in the service.

I have tried debugging with System.out.println() and fond where it stops working but cant work out why it all looks good.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        System.out.println("test 1");
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        System.out.println("test 2");
        LocationListener lli = new myLocationListener();
        System.out.println("test 3");
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, lli);

        System.out.println("test 4");



        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

 class myLocationListener implements LocationListener{



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(location != null){

            pet.setMeter();


        }

    }
```

It gets to Test 4 then dies. I am lost at why so if anyone can help that would be awesome thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice gps tracker guide: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Just needed to add this.mLocation = location in onLocationChanged

He also wraps it into a service.

Comment: True, will do so when I get to my computer